# I keep getting the error "string index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm doing some homework and i'm kinda stumped, the assignment is to create a program that makes a email address based on your first and last name and the year you started school, but for some reason I cant get the email to generate I keep getting the "String index out of range" error.
Here is the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/simps/Desktop/email.py", line 58, in <module>
    emailOutput = Text(Point(200,350), fst_name[0] + lst_name + YEAR + "@student.kathycollege.edu")
IndexError: string index out of range
Here is my code:

# a graphical program that creates a student email adress
from graphics import *
import math
#setting up the window
win = GraphWin("email",400,400)
win.setBackground("yellow")
#setting up the input
instructions = Text(Point(160,50), "For your email, enter your first and last name,\n and the year you are starting school.")
instructions.draw(win)
fstName = Text(Point(100,100),"What is your first name?: ")
fstName.draw(win)
fstNameInput = Entry(Point(260,100), 10)
fstNameInput.draw(win)
lstName = Text(Point(100,150), "what is your last name?: ")
lstName.draw(win)
lstNameInput = Entry(Point(260,150), 15)
lstNameInput.draw(win)
year = Text(Point(130,200), "What year are you starting school?: ")
year.draw(win)
yearInput = Entry(Point(280,200), 4)
yearInput.draw(win)
#Line break
linBreak = Text(Point(200,289), "=======================================")
linBreak.draw(win)
#Output
email = Text(Point(50,315), "Your email is: ")
email.draw(win)
emailOutput = Entry(Point(200,340), 50)
emailOutput.draw(win)
#setting up The process
fst_name = fstNameInput.getText()
lst_name = lstNameInput.getText()
YEAR = yearInput.getText()
#Button
button = Rectangle(Point(130,250),Point(210,279))
button.draw(win)
buttonCenter = button.getCenter()
buttonText = Text(buttonCenter, "Enter")
buttonText.draw(win)
#button function (got help for this on stack overflow)
def inside(point, rectangle):


    ll = rectangle.getP1()
    ur = rectangle.getP2()  

    return ll.getX() < point.getX() < ur.getX() and ll.getY() < point.getY() < ur.getY()


while True:
    click = win.getMouse()

    if click is None:
        emailOutput.setText("")
    elif inside(click, button):
        emailOutput.setText(fst_name[0] + lst_name + YEAR + "@student.kathycollege.edu")
        break;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. As such, we cannot reproduce your error. In addition, please provide a full traceback of your error.

Comment: Your values for `fst_name`, `lst_name ` and `YEAR` are only set when the program is initiated. Should they be updated each time a textbox is changed? When you try to call `emailOutput.setText(fst_name[0],...)` the variable is more than likely empty

Comment: Hello :) Here at Stack Overflow, the Question and Answer format is distinct to that of many other forums. Specifically, the title should strictly reflect the question at hand, without including words meant as tags, which are already at the foot of your question. Also, there is no need to add "Solved" or any other indication to your question. The proper way to mark your issue as done or solved is to accept the answer that most helped you. For more information, see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/363946)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to move the getText variables to the button command so those would only happen after i clicked the button

Answer (score 0):

The error message would help.
But based on my eye-balling, the error could happen at the line at the end :

`emailOutput.setText(fst_name[0] + lst_name + YEAR + "@student.kathycollege.edu")`

when the `fst_name` is empty, `fst_name[0]` will throw the index out of range error. I don't think you need `[0]` here, or you may want to deal with the no-first-name case separately.

Comment: Oh my bad, here is the error messege,                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/simps/Desktop/email.py", line 58, in <module>
    emailOutput = Text(Point(200,350), fst_name[0] + lst_name + YEAR + "@student.kathycollege.edu")
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: the assignment calls for the email to start with the first letter of the first name, I thought adding the button to have the email address show up after its clicked would  mean it would mean the text would be their when its clicked